# How do I disable touchpad while typying in Ubuntu 18.04 with LXDE?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, indicator, lxde

I installed Touchpad indicator recently. At the beginning it did disable the touchpad for 2 seconds after typing, even though the delay was supposed to be only 300 miliseconds. Anyway,something unkown happened yesterday because "Touchpapd indicator" does not disable the touchpad any more while typing.

Does anyone have any idea to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt update && sudo apt install touchpad-indicator
```

To disable touch-pad while typing, open the program and select the respective option from Preferences -> Actions.

Then add the app to the startup list.

Preferences -> General options tab.

Comment: Thanks. I rebooted the computer and it got fixed. I do not know whether I changed something else though.

Comment: No problem, have a nice day